# R-How to flip coordinates of a Spatial point Data Frame in the plot

Tags: r, plot, gis, r-sp

I am using "sp" package to plot a spatial point data frame.

Below are my codes

```
    plot(SpatialDataAll,col="blue")
    plot(SpatialData,col="red",add=T)
    plot(SpatialDatafew,col="green",add=T)
```

The image I'm getting is [Image in R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5goj.png)
But the coordinates are flipped as I need the image [Australian map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J2hx.gif)

The coordinates in x-axis should be between 100 to 160 and in y-axis between -40 to -10. In the graph I'm getting in R, x and y are flipped. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you could access the SpatialData `coords` section and reorder the coordinate columns where column one contains the x-coordinates shown in your example image.

`SpatialData@coords[, c(2,1)]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, in Spatial R graphs, should longitude be in x-axis and Lattitude in y-axis?

Comment: Yes, latitude is parallel to the equator (i.e. North-South) and longitude is perpendicular to the equator (East-West). Hopefully by switching the two you get the plot you're after!

Comment: I remember having a similar issue a few months back, glad I could help.